# I want some of the thread groups to run simultaneously and others one after the other

Tags: jmeter

I have 7 threads in my test plan. I would like the first 4 threads to run simultaneously but the last 3 i want to run one after the other.
I tried using a constant timer to delay the last 3 but there is no real way to know when one finishes in order to set the right delay on the timer.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Consecutively = one after another. Did you mean "concurrently"?

Comment: @AliesBelik yes i meant concurrently.. sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using a constant timer to delay the last 3 but there is no real way to know when one finishes in order to set the right delay on the timer.

In the Thread Group there is a `Scheduler`-options which let you set the `Duration` of the thread group. This way you know how long the thread groups run and can delay the last thread groups accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do similar thing using **[Ultimate Thread Group](https://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup)** plugin